# Spark Listener EventLoggingListener threw an exception / ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: apache-spark

In our application (Spark 2.0.1) we have this exception popping up frequently.
I can't find anything about this.
What could be the cause ?

```
16/10/27 11:18:24 ERROR LiveListenerBus: Listener EventLoggingListener threw an exception
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
    at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:43)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:183)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:45)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.to(TraversableLike.scala:590)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.to(Traversable.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toList(TraversableOnce.scala:294)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.toList(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$.accumValueToJson(JsonProtocol.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$$anonfun$accumulableInfoToJson$5.apply(JsonProtocol.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$$anonfun$accumulableInfoToJson$5.apply(JsonProtocol.scala:291)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$.accumulableInfoToJson(JsonProtocol.scala:291)
    at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$$anonfun$taskInfoToJson$12.apply(JsonProtocol.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$$anonfun$taskInfoToJson$12.apply(JsonProtocol.scala:283)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.foreach(ListBuffer.scala:45)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$.taskInfoToJson(JsonProtocol.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$.taskEndToJson(JsonProtocol.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$.sparkEventToJson(JsonProtocol.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.logEvent(EventLoggingListener.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.onTaskEnd(EventLoggingListener.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerBus$class.doPostEvent(SparkListenerBus.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.doPostEvent(LiveListenerBus.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.doPostEvent(LiveListenerBus.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus$class.postToAll(ListenerBus.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.postToAll(LiveListenerBus.scala:36)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:79)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:78)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1249)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1.run(LiveListenerBus.scala:77)
```

**EDIT:** One more information, our application is long-running, and to resume from potentially failed spark context, we use the SparkBuilder.getOrCreate() method between two "jobs". Could this mess-up with the listeners ?

Comment: This is cropping up again for Spark 3.1.1 (EMR v6.3.0). Seems like something went wrong again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a known problem in `Spark 2.0.1` ([SPARK-17816](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17816)) and will be fixed with `Spark 2.0.2/2.1.0` ([related pull request](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/15425)).

To get rid of the exception without waiting for `Spark 2.0.2/2.1.0`, clone the [latest, unstable spark version](https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/branch-2.0) and [build apache-spark manually](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html).

**Update:** They released [`Spark 2.0.2`](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html)!

Comment: I couldn't find one, but it should be obsolete with the release of ``Spark 2.0.2``

Answer (score 3):

We also just upgraded to Spark 2.0.1 and started seeing the same exception. We narrowed the cause down to a section of Python code containing the following idiom:

```
a = spark_context.textFile('..')
a = a.map(stuff)
b = a.filter(stuff).map(stuff)
```

I've had issues in the past with variable self-assignment in Spark, but after upgrading to 2.0.1 the problem got really acute and we started seeing  ConcurrentModification exceptions.

The fix for us was simply changing the code to not do any self-assignments.

Comment: After upgrading to `Spark 2.0.1`, I get the same error message and I don't have any variable self-assignment in my code.

Comment: "self-assignments" are not a thing. When you say `a = a.map(stuff)` you are not assigning to the variable `a` the new DataFrame from the old `a`, but the old reference isn't lost, because it's referenced by the resulting DataFrame in the dependency graph. I think that you are really seeing something else.

Comment: @vy32 , so how do we handle it ? should we create an empty Dataframe everytime and assign to it ?

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue has surfaced in Spark 3.1.0, related to `EventLoggingListener` race condition and is described in the following bug reports:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-34731
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-32027

The issue was fixed in Spark 3.1.2, so upgrading Spark from 3.1.0/3.1.1 to 3.1.2 would solve it. Alternatively, it is possible to avoid the error by disabling event logging altogether:

```
spark.eventLog.enabled=false
```