# Spark `LiveListenerBus` Exception is freaking me out

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, spark-graphx

I'm using AWS EMR clusters, and the spark version is

```
spark-submit --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.0.1
      /_/

Branch HEAD
Compiled by user ec2-user on 2016-10-11T00:04:18Z
Revision 8182b3893b6ce47724d35a32fbea3605a0d9cb98
Url git@aws157git.com:/pkg/Aws157BigTop
```

I run some Spark `GraphX` jobs on the cluster and the data is in json format (gzipped, stored on aws s3). I found that, if the data is small (like around 1000 lines), the submitted jobs will run ok without any error or exception, but if I increase the data size (like around 1m lines), then the `LiveListenerBus` exception coming down like diarrhea, which really freaks me out :-(

I tried to tune parameters likes `--num-executors,--executor-memory`, doesn't help at all.

Jobs submitted like this,

`spark-submit --class "MyJob" --master yarn mypkg.jar   // if do --master local, no exception`

Exception like this,

```
17/06/11 11:18:58 ERROR LiveListenerBus: Listener EventLoggingListener threw an exception
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
        at scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$JIteratorWrapper.next(Wrappers.scala:43)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:183)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:45)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.to(TraversableLike.scala:590)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.to(Traversable.scala:104)
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toList(TraversableOnce.scala:294)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.toList(Traversable.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$.accumValueToJson(JsonProtocol.scala:314)
        at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$$anonfun$accumulableInfoToJson$5.apply(JsonProtocol.scala:291)
        at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$$anonfun$accumulableInfoToJson$5.apply(JsonProtocol.scala:291)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
        at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$.accumulableInfoToJson(JsonProtocol.scala:291)
        at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$$anonfun$taskInfoToJson$12.apply(JsonProtocol.scala:283)
        at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$$anonfun$taskInfoToJson$12.apply(JsonProtocol.scala:283)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at scala.collection.generic.TraversableForwarder$class.foreach(TraversableForwarder.scala:35)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.foreach(ListBuffer.scala:45)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$.taskInfoToJson(JsonProtocol.scala:283)
        at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$.taskEndToJson(JsonProtocol.scala:145)
        at org.apache.spark.util.JsonProtocol$.sparkEventToJson(JsonProtocol.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.logEvent(EventLoggingListener.scala:137)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.EventLoggingListener.onTaskEnd(EventLoggingListener.scala:157)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerBus$class.doPostEvent(SparkListenerBus.scala:45)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.doPostEvent(LiveListenerBus.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.doPostEvent(LiveListenerBus.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.util.ListenerBus$class.postToAll(ListenerBus.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus.postToAll(LiveListenerBus.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(LiveListenerBus.scala:79)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(LiveListenerBus.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1249)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus$$anon$1.run(LiveListenerBus.scala:77)
```

OK, I searched SO and [people say this is a known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40286001/2235936), which could be fixed by upgrading Spark to newer version. HOWEVER, looks like I am the only one of the team experiencing this issue (**maybe because other guys are not doing `GraphX` jobs?**)

My question,

1) Could this exception relate to the `GraphX` package of Spark?

2) How to fix it? Do I have to upgrade the Spark? And how to upgrade on AWS?

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` occured because when the iterator is doing `iterator.hasNext()` the iterator object changed such as update,remove and son on.

Comment: So you mean, this exception could be a bug in my code?

Comment: yeah,you should check your code especially for the iterator.